# Shiny Server not able to load installed package

Tags: r, shiny-server, shinydashboard

I have a problem deploying my application to Shiny Server.

The application is loading (or at least the ui.R is loaded) so I'm able to see the user interface. But the execution stops there, and the following is dumped to my JS console:

```
Attaching package: ‘shinydashboard’

The following object is masked from ‘package:graphics’:

box

Loading required package: bitops Error in library(data.table) : there
  is no package called ‘data.table’
```

The last line is indicating the problem to be the `data.table` package.

I checked my Shiny Server installation and `data.table` is correctly installed. I can load the package in my R console on the server, both as normal user and as `sudo` user.

I'm not even using this package directly, so I guess it's some sort of dependency.

Do you have any idea?

**Edit:** The minimal example of this problem is reproducible by using the lesson 1 example from the shiny tutorial: http://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/lesson1/ and including `library(data.table)`

If you need the `data.table` package for combining data.frames, 
I found some workaround by using the `dplyr` function `rbind_all` instead of `rbindlist` from `data.table` (keep in mind this is significantly slower)

Comment: Try using `lib=` option of `library()` and give full path to packages folder

Comment: library(data.table) has recently been deprecated for library(DT) - perhaps try loading that last of your packages at the top of your script.  Also make sure every library is updated, in some cases I have had to use the install_github versions of packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks you @lbollar and @MarkeD!
Installing the `chron` package and the `install_github` version of `data.table` fixed my problem.

Answer (score 2):

When I recently deployed shiny on an ec2 instance, I had a similar problem. Run library() without parameters and take a look at your different package directories. I believe the default directory for packages that shiny uses that my image came with is '/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’.

When I install packages, I make sure to explicitly state the path to be installed with lib=, `install.packages("data.table",lib="/usr/local/lib/R/site-library")`

Comment: I followed your instructions and got this path:
`/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/library`. I reinstalled the package in the instructed way, but the app isn't working.

Comment: Are you able to use other packages in a shiny app that are located in that directory? Are you running from rstudio or is this actually deployed on a shiny-server?

Comment: It is deployed on a shiny-server. Yes I can use other packages, I also updated all packages to the versions used in RStudio (where the app is working fine).

Comment: Sorry, I didn't think it would require this. Could you edit original post to include a minimal reproducible example, and include the output of sessionInfo().

Comment: So I was able to reproduce your error when I launched from shiny-server. For me, installing the package "chron" (making sure to install to the correct directory using lib= again) fixed this. I got the same error as you in js console, but then it also said it failed to find package chron. Installing chron took away all errors. I am using R 3.1.3

Comment: Also, if that doesn't work, I would look at this page [data.table](http://crantastic.org/packages/data-table) and make sure that everything data.table uses is in fact installed in the correct directory.